# Tracing a line along local maxima in Matlab

Tags: matlab, function, graph, line

I have a 2D image consisting in the simulation of a band structure [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLyKz.png). I would like to track the maxima on the image to have lines (indicating the bands). The first thing that I did is to calculate the maxima in each line (showed in [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSpjO.png)). Then I have a set of points. However, I dont know how to connect each of the points. Does Matlab have a function capable of doing that? Or is there any reasonable way for doing it? So far, I am connecting the points by hand, but that is not scalable.

Many thanks

[contourplot showing the raw data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLyKz.png)
[plot showing the maxima of the colorplot in (1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSpjO.png)

Comment: you mean straight lines or just 1d curves?

Comment: also, if you wrote some code, please include it in the question.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, please clarify some more. You have calculated the maxima along... what lines? And you want to connect the maxima into... a line? On one hand, this sounds like you want to **group neighboring points together**, like the function `bwconncomp` [doc](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwconncomp.html). On the other hand, it's like you want a **contour plot**, to show the bands; or maybe **cluster points together**? Also, the third image is the same as the second image; I don't think you've linked that correctly. Please clarify.

Comment: you can look into `bwskel`.  https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwskel.html